# java: records are not supported in -source 15

Tags: java, version, record

I have problem with records in Java, currently added in repo. I do get a problem:

> "java: records are not supported in -source 15 (use -source 16 or higher to enable records)"

I have changed language level to 15(Preview), but that does not help. Looking for a solution to compile this.

[image]

Comment: I think IDEA drops support of preview features of older JDKs when the feature is available properly in a released JDK. Records were a preview feature in Java 15, so IDEA no longer supports it there. Use Java 16 if you want to use records in IDEA.  [This blog post seems to confirm that](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/07/support-for-java-13-preview-features-in-intellij-idea-2019-2/), but talks about older preview features.

Comment: I have updated to java 16, but that did not help. Now I get "java: invalid source release 15 with --enable-preview
  (preview language features are only supported for release 16)"

Comment: @JoachimSauer [This blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/09/java-17-and-intellij-idea/) shows the dialog box warning: *Newer IDE versions may discontinue support for preview features.*

Answer (score 7):

Solved, had to change Java version in all the places.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbs4f.png)